# How to rotate the font in Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

How do you rotate the font for `xlabel` or `ylabel` in the Julia plotting package Plots.jl?

```
fo = font(10, "Courier")
fo.rotation = 90
plot(randn(10), xtickfont=fo) # Does nothing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword arguments to rotate the fonts are

```
plot(..., xrotation = 45) # For 45 degree rotation
plot(..., yrotation = 45)
plot(...,  rotation = 45) # Rotates both x and y fonts
```

More attributes are provided at http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/

Comment: It changes the ticks, not the labels!